# How did Barry keep up with his special diet in jail?

Tags: plot-explanation, arrowverse, the-flash

In one of the earlier seasons its apparent that Barry need an insane amount of calories to run so how does he keep up with this while he's in jail?

Comment: Maybe he isn't allowed to run in jail and so doesn't burn up calories fast and has to wait until he is released to resume his special diet and be able to run as super speed.

Comment: he was running while he was in normal jail, we saw him run at least twice: when he stops the big fight, and when he runs his friend to china

Comment: But he is also fast enough to run to *China* and back in the time it takes a security camera to do one turn. So presumably he is fast enough to run out, grab a lot of food, eat it and return in the same time.  Or maybe Cisco does *breach delivery*.

Answer (score -2):

I believe barry needs to eat a lot, only when he is using a lot amount of speed force. Since in Jail he isn't running much he could manage with an Ordinary diet... or he might have been sneaking out to get food and return to his cell